# LINQ, first record in each group only if condition inside FirstOrDefault is met

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a main table and a table that contains the translations of this table.

- Table1

  - Id
  - Description
- Table2

  - Table1_Id
  - Language
  - TranslatedValue

To get the grouped values I can left join the first table with the second and group by the Id and the Description of the first table.

Now I want to be able to filter the data by the TranslatedValue on the Language requested by the user and at the same time keep the total languages that the Table1 can have.

I have implemented something like this:

```cs
var userLanguage = "EN";
var translatedFilter = "TranslatedValue";

var query = from main in _context.Table1
            from translated in _context.Table2.Where(x => x.Table1_Id == main.Id)
            group translated by new { main.Id, main.Description } into g
            where
            translatedFilter == null || (g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == userLanguage) != null && g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == userLanguage).TranslatedValue.Contains(translatedFilter))
            select new ResultObject
            {
               Id = g.Key.Id,
               Description = g.Key.Description,
               TranslatedDescription = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == userLanguage) != null ? g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == userLanguage).TranslatedValue : g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == "EN").TranslatedValue != null ? g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == "EN").TranslatedValue : null,
               LanguageList = g.Select(x => x.Language)
            }
```

This query returns "***Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Query.Internal.EntityProjectionExpression'***" when I execute it in the unit tests, so I guess there is something EFcore is not able to translate .

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `g` come from? Shouldn't it be `group translated by new { main.Id, main.Description } into g` ?

Comment: yes sorry, I wrote this query by hand, so there can be some errors, but the logic is alright

Comment: Looks like In-Memory DB doesn't support that kind of projection. Maybe use normal conditional aggregation `where g.Count(x => x.Language == userLanguage && x.TranslatedValue.Contains(translatedFilter)) > 0`

Comment: I don't get this error with a real SQL Server DB and EF Core 8.0.2. Without knowing the exact definition of the involved classes and the DbContext, it is very difficult to reproduce the error and to give you advice.

Comment: I also don't get the error with an empty in-memory DB.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have changed a bit how I retrieve the data, didn't thought all that code was relevant sorry, apparently when i use `g.Count(x => x.Language == userLanguage) > 0` instead of `g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == userLanguage) != null` it works...